# can I use YouTube Videos as main content on my Facebook Application?

Tags: facebook, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I'd like to create a Faceook application which is same like Socialcam but in a different aspect, which is sports.

I can get the user Page Likes which are sports and create the video playlist according to them, in the process or creating the list of videos I would like to use Gdata api and use Youtube to pull youtube videos.

Is that possible and is there any restrictions on that from the Youtube?

Thanks all

Edit:
It seems this is not possible as far as I can see by Googling and reading their Terms because I need to run Ads on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using YouTube videos in a Facebook application is quite possible and relatively very easy (though you need to check each one has the embed flag set).

Whether you are allowed to depends on whether your application is monetised (i.e. runs ads or the user pays for it) and if the videos are the main content where they're displayed within it.  The full terms of service are available at http://www.youtube.com/t/terms